Azure Dev Ops: Work items must be linked error
We are seeing an issue with creating PRs when we have a policy in check that all commits must have a work item.
Here is the error:


We could not find a pull request that we were merging that did not have a work item related.
What is the fix for this?
We had to remove the policies, create the PR, and then add the policies back to resolve the issue.
We did have over 200 linked work items. Is there a bug that occurs once there is over 200?
Thanks.

The policy isn't that all commits have a linked work item, it's that the pull request needs to have an associated work item.

If have enabled "Check for linked work items" as Required check on the target branch of PR, under the right Work items section of the PR Overview tab, you can see which work items are linked to the PR. If no work items listed, the check will get failed.

You can link work items to the PR via the following ways:

Manually link work items under the right Work items section of the PR Overview tab.

Before creating the PR, link work items to the commits on the source branch. When creating the PR, the work items will be automatically linked to the PR.

After creating the PR, link work items when pushing new commits to the the source branch. The work items will be automatically linked to the PR.


Note:
After creating the PR, if you link work items to the existing commits on the source branch, the work items will not be automatically linked to the PR.


We had a lot of work items connected below and on the right where the Work Items section is. If we see the error, connect a new work item on the right in the Work Items Section, and then we should be fine? That will fix the policy by adding a new work item to the other commit(s) that, in the past, were missing a tag for a work item on the commit.

@tvbRPTI2754, As stated above, After having created the PR, if you link work items to the existing commits on the source branch, the work items will not be automatically linked to the PR. To link new work items to the PR, you can try with the 3 ways mentioned above.
